# After applying bootstrap, dropdown of navbar is not working in meteor

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

HTML code within head tag

```
<head>
<title>Open</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.5/basic/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
```

HTML code within body tag

```
 <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
     <div class="container-fluid">
       <div class="navbar-header">
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
         <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="/">Open</a>
       </div>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav fontModify">
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href= '/addAP'>Link1</a></li>         
           <li><a href= '/addAT'>Link2</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**The problem is that the "link" button does not expand into the "link1" and "link2" buttons when clicked.** The "link" button has become unresponsive. The "link" button is in the **a class= "dropdown-toggle"**. I do not think that I am making any basic mistake. **Can anyone help me regarding this**.
The whole code was working fine with the previous version of meteor but somehow it has stopped working with the latest version.
Apologies for making any mistake while posting the question or diverting from any programming conventions. I am new to programming.
Thanking everyone

Comment: your code is working fine for me, here's the fiddle i created https://jsfiddle.net/559sxfjn/

Comment: @Sujoy, i have checked your code and its working fine. See here http://jsfiddle.net/opmnzt1m/

Comment: Any idea why it is not working locally? No it is working in the fiddle but not here locally.

Comment: its working , https://jsfiddle.net/MadhawaMB/559sxfjn/1/
I think its overwrite for other JS file, please  check it ,

Comment: @Cola I could not understand your point. What is "overwrite for other JS file"?

Comment: i told, sometime not working some script to overwrite

Comment: Agree with vanburen, add only once and in proper way or else js will conflict.

Comment: please remove following script, and run agein your local machine

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me out. The answer by Vanburen has solved my problem.

Comment: Than you so much @Cola

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're loading your scripts twice: once in the head and once before the closing body tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

You should only have one

Sidenote: You're also missing the `href="#"` on your `dropdown-toggle`.

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. Your answer has solved my problem. Thank you so much

Comment: sir, @Vanburen ,i agree with you

Answer (score 1):

I added this package and my dropdowns started working fine > matb33:bootstrap-dropdowns.